# Set of equations describing general triangle only numerically solvable using sympy

Tags: geometry, sympy, solver

I have two triangles sharing side c. Knowns are angles alpha,alpha' and side a and a'. I am looking for b and b'.
[image: triangles]
[image]
From the set of 3 cosine rules I can find e.g. b' as shown in the code below. Unfortunately there are 2 solutions after every solve, from which I pick the correct one manually and in the end I have to solve numerically for the solution, which is correct.

Can I somehow deduce which solution after solving is the correct one or put some constraints on solve?
Is there a closed solution to my problem?

```
from mpmath import radians
from sympy import N, symbols, cos, init_printing,Eq,solve,simplify,nsolve

init_printing()

alphaPrime, alpha, a, aPrime, b, bPrime,c   = symbols('αprime α a aprime b bprime,c')

eq1=Eq( a**2          , b**2+c**2-2*b*c*cos(alpha))
eq2=Eq( aPrime**2     , bPrime**2+c**2-2*bPrime*c*cos(alphaPrime))
eq3=Eq( (a+aPrime)**2 , bPrime**2+b**2-2*b*bPrime*cos(alpha+alphaPrime))

eq1c=solve(eq1,c,simplify=False)
eq2c=solve(eq2,c,simplify=False)
Eq1MinusEq2=eq1c[1]-eq2c[0]
eq1_eq2_b=solve(Eq1MinusEq2,b,simplify=False)

eq3_b=solve(eq3,b,simplify='False')
eq_1n2_Minus_eq3=eq1_eq2_b[1]-eq3_b[1]
display(simplify(eq_1n2_Minus_eq3))
expr=eq_1n2_Minus_eq3.subs([(aPrime,1.6547),(a,1.1),(alphaPrime,radians(27.031)), 
(alpha,radians(25.268))])
display(nsolve(expr,bPrime,1)) ##works
```

gives me: 3.45613973389693+1.86640158050948⋅10−8, which's real part is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your equations:

```
In [156]: eq1
Out[156]: 
 2    2                   2
a  = b  - 2⋅b⋅c⋅cos(α) + c 

In [157]: eq2
Out[157]: 
  2     2                     2
a′  = b′  - 2⋅b′⋅c⋅cos(α′) + c 

In [158]: eq3
Out[158]: 
        2    2                          2
(a + a′)  = b  - 2⋅b⋅b′⋅cos(α + α′) + b′
```

We want to eliminate `c` and then solve for `a` and `a'` so let's eliminate `c` first:

```
In [159]: eq12 = resultant(eq1, eq2, c)

In [160]: eq12
Out[160]: 
 4      2   2      2  2      2                          2   2    2          2   2     4       2  2  ↪
a  - 2⋅a ⋅a′  - 2⋅a ⋅b  + 4⋅a ⋅b⋅b′⋅cos(α)⋅cos(α′) - 4⋅a ⋅b′ ⋅cos (α′) + 2⋅a ⋅b′  + a′  - 4⋅a′ ⋅b ⋅ ↪

↪    2          2  2       2                           2   2    4      3                        2   ↪
↪ cos (α) + 2⋅a′ ⋅b  + 4⋅a′ ⋅b⋅b′⋅cos(α)⋅cos(α′) - 2⋅a′ ⋅b′  + b  - 4⋅b ⋅b′⋅cos(α)⋅cos(α′) + 4⋅b ⋅b ↪

↪  2    2         2   2    2          2   2         3                    4
↪ ′ ⋅cos (α) + 4⋅b ⋅b′ ⋅cos (α′) - 2⋅b ⋅b′  - 4⋅b⋅b′ ⋅cos(α)⋅cos(α′) + b′
```

Now `eq12` and `eq3` are two equations for the two unknowns `a` and `a'`.

We can eliminate say `a'` to find an equation only for `a`. This equation is a quartic with two double roots that we can simplify down to nice expressions:

```
In [167]: eq_a = resultant(eq12, eq3, aPrime)

In [178]: r1, r2 = roots(eq_a, a)

In [179]: r2.expand(trig=True).simplify()
Out[179]: 
      ____________________________________________
     ╱  2 ⎛ 2                          2⎞    2    
    ╱  b ⋅⎝b  - 2⋅b⋅b′⋅cos(α + α′) + b′ ⎠⋅sin (α) 
   ╱   ────────────────────────────────────────── 
  ╱                                    2          
╲╱              (b⋅sin(α) + b′⋅sin(α′))           

In [180]: r1.expand(trig=True).simplify()
Out[180]: 
       ____________________________________________
      ╱  2 ⎛ 2                          2⎞    2    
     ╱  b ⋅⎝b  - 2⋅b⋅b′⋅cos(α + α′) + b′ ⎠⋅sin (α) 
-   ╱   ────────────────────────────────────────── 
   ╱                                    2          
 ╲╱              (b⋅sin(α) + b′⋅sin(α′))
```

These are the two solutions for `a`. Corresponding solutions for `a'` can be found similarly and are the same apart from interchanging primes which only affects the final `sin(α)` part of the numerator.

The multiple solutions are to do with the equations being satisfied by negative angles and lengths. If we want to require everything to be positive then the formulae above can simplify because most factors under the square root are squares of positive quantities.

The key technique used above is polynomial resultants:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.resultant

EDIT: I see that b and b' are the unknowns. Okay so adapted:

```
In [59]: eq_b = resultant(eq12, eq3, bPrime)

In [60]: from sympy.simplify.fu import TR5

In [61]: eq_b2 = TR5((eq_b).expand(trig=True)).expand()

In [64]: r1, r2 = roots(eq_b2, b)

In [74]: r1
Out[74]: 
       ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
      ╱                                                                        2         2 ⎛ 2    2                                             2    2   ⎞    2                                                                           
     ╱                                                                        a ⋅(a + a′) ⋅⎝a ⋅sin (α′) - 2⋅a⋅a′⋅sin(α)⋅sin(α′)⋅cos(α + α′) + a′ ⋅sin (α)⎠⋅sin (α′)                                                                       
-   ╱   ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
   ╱     4    4          3              3                      2   2    4       2          2   2    3       3                      2   2    2       4          2   2    2       2             3    3                            4    4    
 ╲╱     a ⋅sin (α′) - 4⋅a ⋅a′⋅sin(α)⋅sin (α′)⋅cos(α + α′) - 4⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′) - 8⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′)⋅cos(α + α′) - 4⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′) + 6⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′) - 4⋅a⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin(α′)⋅cos(α + α′) + a′ ⋅sin (α) 

In [75]: r2
Out[75]: 
      ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
     ╱                                                                        2         2 ⎛ 2    2                                             2    2   ⎞    2                                                                           
    ╱                                                                        a ⋅(a + a′) ⋅⎝a ⋅sin (α′) - 2⋅a⋅a′⋅sin(α)⋅sin(α′)⋅cos(α + α′) + a′ ⋅sin (α)⎠⋅sin (α′)                                                                       
   ╱   ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
  ╱     4    4          3              3                      2   2    4       2          2   2    3       3                      2   2    2       4          2   2    2       2             3    3                            4    4    
╲╱     a ⋅sin (α′) - 4⋅a ⋅a′⋅sin(α)⋅sin (α′)⋅cos(α + α′) - 4⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′) - 8⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′)⋅cos(α + α′) - 4⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′) + 6⋅a ⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin (α′) - 4⋅a⋅a′ ⋅sin (α)⋅sin(α′)⋅cos(α + α′) + a′ ⋅sin (α)
```

There might be ways to simplify those.

Comment: This looks very convenient, but the unknowns are b and b' not a and a'. When adapting to eq_b = resultant(eq12, eq3, bPrime)
r1, r2 = roots(eq_b, b) then roots fails with: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: With a bit of simplification `roots` can find radical formulae.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```py
alphaPrime, alpha, a, aPrime, b, bPrime,c   = symbols('αprime α a aprime b bprime,c')

# substitution dictionary
sd = {
    aPrime: 1.6547,
    a: 1.1,
    alphaPrime: radians(27.031), 
    alpha: radians(25.268)
}

# rewrite as addition in order to be modified easily
eq1=Eq( a**2          , b**2+c**2-2*b*c*cos(alpha)).rewrite(Add)
eq2=Eq( aPrime**2     , bPrime**2+c**2-2*bPrime*c*cos(alphaPrime)).rewrite(Add)
eq3=Eq( (a+aPrime)**2 , bPrime**2+b**2-2*b*bPrime*cos(alpha+alphaPrime)).rewrite(Add)

# laws of sines (hint: draw the angles and note that beta + betaPrime = 180)
eq4 = Eq(b / bPrime, a / aPrime * sin(alphaPrime) / sin(alpha))
eq4 = Eq(*[term*bPrime for term in eq4.args])

# equations to be solved
e1 = (eq1 - eq2).subs(*eq4.args)
e2 = eq3.subs(*eq4.args)
display(e1, e2)
```

[image]

```py
sols = solve([e1, e2], [bPrime, c], dict=True)
# after the symbolic solution is computed, substitutes the numerical values
sols = [{k: v.subs(sd) for k, v in d.items()} for d in sols]
# filter out the solution to keep only the positive one.
# The assumption is that one of them will have negative numbers
sols = [s for s in sols if all(v>0 for v in s.values())][0]
sols
```

[image]

```py
eq4.subs(sd).subs(sols)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the algebra goes something like this (subject to typos):

```
a^2 = b^2   + c^2 - 2bc.cos(alpha)     (1)
a'^2 = b'^2 + c^2 - 2b'c.cos(alpha')   (2)
(a+a')^2 = b^2 + b'^2 - 2b'b.cos(alpha+alpha')  (3)
from (1) we can solve a quadratic for b (or b' from (2))
0 = b^2 - 2bc.cos(alpha) + (c^2-a^2)     (4)
Hence
b =  bc.cos(alpha) +/- sqrt( (c.cos(alpha))^2 - c^2 + a^2)
b =  bc.cos(alpha) +/- sqrt( a^2 - (c.sin(alpha))^2))    (5)
b' = b'c.cos(alpha') +/- sqrt( a'^2 - (c.sin(alpha'))^2))    (6)

(3)-(1)-(2)
2a'a = 2c(b.cos(alpha) + b'.cos(alpha')) - 2b'b.cos(alpha+alpha')   (7)
a =  [c(b.cos(alpha) + b'.cos(alpha'))-b'b.cos(alpha+alpha')]/a'    (8)

from (2)
a' = sqrt(b'^2 + c^2 - 2b'c.cos(alpha'))  (9)

subst (9) in (8)
a = [c(b.cos(alpha) + b'.cos(alpha'))-b'b.cos(alpha+alpha')]/sqrt(b'^2+c^2-2b'c.cos(alpha'))    (10)

subst (5) and (6) in (10) - too messy to type in!
```

That is the pure algebraic solution (subject to typos) with the RHS now entirely in terms of the values b,b',c, alpha, alpha' subst (5) & (6) here. Note that both quadratics have two roots (5), (6). I'm guessing here that the positive ones are probably the ones you want but it could be either.

Comment: Does this solution consider that a , a' , alpha , alpha' are given and not c? What is the point of subsititung b in eq10 with with eq5, since eq5 contains b on both sides?